# Custom Middleware error even after implemented

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am using API call via Async-Await that requires a custom middleware, I am using Thunk as custom Middleware. All dependencies are installed. Then also, somehow it fails to detect the middleware or something like that.

My code when executed shows the following error:
[image: Error Page]

This is my **Actions** Page: I used Async-Await which led me to this error

```
import axios from "axios";

export const saveTwitterToken = (token) => {
  return ({
    type: TWITTER_OAUTH,
    payload: token
  });
};

export const callTwitterAPI = async (config) => {
  const request = await axios({
    "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": " _Something_ "
    }
  });
  return ({
    type: "api",
    payload: request
  })
};
```

This is my **Index.js** Page:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from './App'
import {Provider} from "react-redux";

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import stores from "./utils/store";

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={stores}>
      <App/>
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root'));
```

This is the **Custom Middleware Store** File:

```
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from '../reducers';

const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  {},
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);
export default store;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to use dispatch for Asynchronous Redux Action as follow:

```
export const callTwitterAPI = config => async dispatch => {
  const request = await axios({
    "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": " _Something_ "
    }
  });

  dispatch({
    type: "api",
    payload: request
  })
}
```

More better way is to use promise as follow:

```
export const callTwitterAPI = config => dispatch => {
  axios({
    "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json",
    "method": "GET",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": " _Something_ "
    }
  }).then(request =>
     dispatch({
       type: "api",
       payload: request
     })
  ).catch(error => handle it OR dispatch another action)
}
```

I hope it help you.